# Bridge two physical interfaces without losing IP connectivity

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

I would like to bridge two physical interfaces (`eth0` and `eth1`) programmatically, without them losing IP connectivity. As soon as I set `eth0`'s master using `sudo ip link set eth0 master br0`, pings will time out. Re-running the DHCP client on the bridge device `br0` will restore connectivity but that violates my requirement of not wanting to lose IP connectivity in the first place.

Is it possible to bridge two physical interfaces without interupting the connection? If so, how?

Comment: If it's done programmatically, have a script configure everything with all output/errors redirected to a file (it would block the script if run manually and remotely otherwise) so at the end the connectivity is working.